# Find the highest and lowest points on the ellipse of intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and the plane $x+y+z=1$

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the highest and lowest points on the ellipse of intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and the plain $x+y+z=1$

Hi i was doing this question but i'm not sure i was right. Does this make sense?

Let

$$f(x) = x^2+y^2 = 1$$
$$f(y) = x+y+z=1, \quad \text{our constraint}$$

$$ \nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x) $$

$f_x = 2x = \lambda$ ..... (1)

$f_y = 2y = \lambda$ ...... (2)

$f_z = 0 = \lambda$

(1) = (2)

$2x = 2y = \lambda = 0 $

$x=y$

Sub into f(x)

$$f(x) = x^2 + x^2 = 1$$ $$f(x) = 2x^2 = 1$$ $$f(x) = x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$ $$ \therefore \, y =  \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Points: $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\right), \quad \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$

Sub these points into g

$$g\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, z \right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} + z = 10 $$ 
$$ z = 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} $$

$$g\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, z \right) = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} + z = 10 $$ 
$$ z = 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} $$

So highest and lowest points are....
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}  \right) \quad lowest$$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}  \right) \quad highest$$

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Does what i did seem right?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to maximize the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$.  Is that what the problem asks?

Comment: @matthew I'm looking for the **highest** and **lowest** points of the ellipse

Comment: So you need extrema of $z$. Which is the same as finding extrema of $x+y$. Which is bounded by $|x+y|\le \sqrt2$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inequality $2x^2+2y^2\geq (x+y)^2$  we indeed have $-\sqrt2 \leq x+y \leq \sqrt{2}$ and to maximize/minimize $z$ we need to minimize/maximize $x+y$ so your solution until $x=y=\pm{1\over\sqrt2}$ is correct.

However how do you get $z$ looks unreasonable as $x+y+z=1$ but your solution, for example ${1\over\sqrt2}+{1\over\sqrt2}+{1\over\sqrt8}$ does not equal $1$.

You should simply calculate $z=1-x-y=1+{\sqrt2}$ for maximum and $1-\sqrt2$ for minimum.

There are two major mistakes after a look at your way of finding z:

(1) $g(x,y,z)=1\neq10$ as stated in the question. I do not know where the $10$ comes from.

(2) $10-{2\over \sqrt2}$ is **not** $8\over\sqrt2$. You cannot calculate irrational numbers like this.

As to answer the comment, what Matthew is talking about is the general way of solving multiple constraints.

We want to maximize $h(x,y,z)=z$ using constraint $g(x,y,z)=x+y+z=1$ and $f(x,y,z)=s^2+y^2=1$. Let the first multiplier be $\lambda$ and the second be $u$

Then we have the system:

$0=\lambda+2ux=\lambda+2uy$

$1=\lambda$

$x^2+y^2=1$

$x+y+z=1$

By solving the equations we will find the value of $z$.

Comment: Hey thanks for spotting those mistakes. I fixed them up and got.... $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}  \right) \quad highest$ and $\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}  \right) \quad lowest$

Comment: Yes these numbers are correct, but the first should be the lowest and the latter should be the highest if you simply compare their $z$ value.

Comment: but if this is correct then what about what Mathew is talking about? $\nabla f(x) = \lambda g(x) + \lambda e(x)  $?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Would this be the same z value as before?

Comment: Yes it will be, when you sub in $\lambda=1$ into the first equation, you will find $x=y$ in terms of $u$ so after solving for $u$, you will end up with the same $x$ and $y$ which must be $\pm {1\over\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not correct.  It looks like you assumed that the first function described in the problem was the objective function (that which is to be optimized) and the second function is the constraint function.

But if you read the problem, you see that both $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x+y+z=1$ are *constraints*.  So you need a Lagrange multiplier approach with *two* multipliers.

But wait!  If these are both constraints, what is the objective function?  Read it again.  What words in the problem say “this is an optimization problem.”  Optimal means superlative, and the superlative words are *highest* and *lowest*.

What function would have its maximum value achieved at the *highest* point of a set?  The *height* function $f(x,y,z) = z$.

---

Here is a fleshed-out solution.  The Lagrange equation is
$$
\nabla (z) = \lambda \nabla (x^2 + y^2) + \mu \nabla (x+y+z)
$$
In coordinates,
\begin{align}
    0 &= \lambda(2x) + \mu \tag{1}\\
    0 &= \lambda(2y) + \mu \tag{2}\\
    1 &= \mu \tag{3}
\end{align}
Then we have the equations of constraint
\begin{align}
    x^2 + y^2 = 1 \tag{4} \\
    x + y + z = 1 \tag{5}
\end{align}

Substituting (3) into (1) and (2) gives
\begin{align*}
    x =y= -\frac{1}{2\lambda}
\end{align*}
Then by (4),
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)^2 + \left(-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)^2 = 1
\implies \lambda^2 = \frac{1}{2} \implies \lambda = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
If $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then $x = y = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and by (5) $z=1+\sqrt{2}$.  If $\lambda = - \frac{1}{2}$ then $x=y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $z=1-\sqrt{2}$.  So the highest point is $\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1+\sqrt{2}\right)$ and the lowest point is $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1-\sqrt{2}\right)$

Comment: So.... $ \nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x) + \mu \times "something"$

Comment: @kingportable: Yep, you got it.

Comment: But i'm confused what would $\mu$ be multiplying? The distance formula? $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Comment: The two constraint functions are $x^2 + y^2$ and $x+y+z$.

Comment: Hi so $\nabla( x^2+y^2-1) = \lambda(x^2+y^2) + \mu (x+y+z)  $?

Comment: I am about to sign off, but if you reread my answer you will find everything you need.

Comment: Thank you for going over it again and adding the working out.  Oh no while **z** is identical **x and y** differ quite a lot. I was hoping we get the same points using 1 or 2 constraints.

Comment: Ah!!.. i see how we could still get the same answer. If you just take the idea that x=y. Then if you sub that in to $x^2+y^2 = 1$ then $x^2+x^2 = 1 $, $2x^2=1$, $x^2=\frac{1}{2}$ hence $x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ $\therefore \, y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ as shown before. Subbing this into $x+y+z=1$ yields.... $z=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$